# Selecting values from a column based on value from another column determined dynamically

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 101:110, C = 201:210)
```

And I want to find values in column A using the following criteria,

```
df$A[df$B > 101 & df$B < 105]
[1] 2 3 4
```

However, I want to be able to specify the criteria programmatically using the following approach,

```
var <- noquote(paste0("df$", names(df[2])))
df$A[var > 101 & var < 105]
```

But all I am getting is `integer(0)`.

Obviously something is not right. Could anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to go through that approach?

Comment: akrun, I intend to cycle through specific columns in that data frame, and extract values from column A that meet the criteria.

Comment: One option is `get` if you are referrring `var <- names(df)[2]; library(data.table);setDT(df)[get(var) > 101 & get(var) < 105]$A
#[1] 2 3 4`

Comment: This is even better! Thanks again akrun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need it, then use `eval(parse`

```
df$A[eval(parse(text=var))> 101 & eval(parse(text=var)) < 105]
#[1] 2 3 4
```